# Handshake failed Android 23

Tags: java, android, ssl, keystore, android-keystore

I've got a problem with Keystores in Android.

I'm trying to connect a client in android to a server in java. My code is working well with API from 15 to 22 of android, but not with the new API 23 update:

i've got the error on the android client:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
```

and this error on the server:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
```

Here's my code, that was working well with API 22 or before:

in client, R.raw.publickey is the public .bks certificate, and R.raw.publickey_v1 is the older version of .bks for compatibility with API 15.

**Server:**

```
public static SSLServerSocket getServerSocketWithCert(int port, InputStream pathToCert, String passwordFromCert) throws IOException,
                                KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException{
    TrustManager[] tmm;
    KeyManager[] kmm;
    KeyStore ks  = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    ks.load(pathToCert, passwordFromCert.toCharArray());
    tmm=tm(ks);
    kmm=km(ks, passwordFromCert);
    SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    ctx.init(kmm, tmm, null);
    SSLServerSocketFactory socketFactory = (SSLServerSocketFactory) ctx.getServerSocketFactory();
    SSLServerSocket ssocket = (SSLServerSocket)        socketFactory.createServerSocket(port);
    return ssocket;
}
private static TrustManager[] tm(KeyStore keystore) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException {
    TrustManagerFactory trustMgrFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    trustMgrFactory.init(keystore);
    return trustMgrFactory.getTrustManagers();
};
private static KeyManager[] km(KeyStore keystore, String password) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
    KeyManagerFactory keyMgrFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    keyMgrFactory.init(keystore, password.toCharArray());
    return keyMgrFactory.getKeyManagers();
};

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SSLServerSocket ss = null;
        try {
            ss = getServerSocketWithCert(12345, Server.class.getResourceAsStream("/privateKey.store"), "password");
        } catch(BindException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (CertificateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while(true){
            SSLSocket s = ss.accept();
            new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream()).writeUTF("test");
            //TODO ERROR IS APPENING HERE
        }
    }
```

**Client:**

```
public static SSLSocket getSocketWithCert(InetAddress ip, int port, InputStream pathToCert, String passwordFromCert) throws IOException,
                                KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, KeyStoreException {
    TrustManager[] tmm;
    KeyStore ks  = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
    ks.load(pathToCert, passwordFromCert.toCharArray());
    tmm=tm(ks);
    SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    ctx.init(null, tmm, null);
    SSLSocketFactory SocketFactory = (SSLSocketFactory) ctx.getSocketFactory();
    SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) SocketFactory.createSocket();
    socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ip, port), 5000);
    return socket;
}

private static TrustManager[] tm(KeyStore keystore) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException {
    TrustManagerFactory trustMgrFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    trustMgrFactory.init(keystore);
    return trustMgrFactory.getTrustManagers();
};
public static void(String[] args){
        int id;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN){
            id = R.raw.publickey;
        } else {
            id = R.raw.publickey_v1;
        }
        try {
            Socket s = SSLSocketKeystoreFactory.getSocketWithCert("myip", 12345, HackerMainActivity.this.getResources().openRawResource(id), "password");
        } catch (UnknownHostException | SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } catch(SocketTimeoutException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } catch (KeyManagementException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | CertificateException | KeyStoreException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        //TODO ERROR IS APPENING HERE
}
```

Thanks a lot for you help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to fix it...

The error was that Android 6.0 is the version that dropped support for SHA-1.
For the one who had the same error, just re-create your certificates using SHA-256...